# Java Pull Table Data from Site?

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

New to Java and I recently started learning how to read HTML from a website using Java but I've been attempting to learn how to parse through it and pull elements(useful data). I have been searching for the best way to do this and Jsoup kept coming up so I decided to try it out. I was able to pull table elements but there is a lot of useless HTML that would be nice to remove.. How can I pull the table from this site and just have the row elements is there an easy way with Jsoup?

```
String html = "http://beta.letsplaysoccer.com/facilities/26/teams/187822";

         Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
         Elements tableElements = doc.select("table");
         System.out.print(tableElements);
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Useless HTML as in the tags, class names, etc.. If I wanted to use this table data I would just want to use say the game dates or something not

```
<td> <a href="/facilities/26/games?exact_date=14-03-30">Sun 03-30-14 07:25 PM</a></td>
```

What I would like to eventually do is pull this data into my own GUI or something

Comment: Can you say something more about `but there is a lot of useless HTML that would be nice to remove..`? Posting example of what you get and what you want would make helping you easier.

Comment: @Timeflies The usual technical term for this is "scraping", ["web scraping"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) in particular (as opposed to "screen scraping" terminal command-line console text). You will find much more info and examples by searching on that term.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks, I am going to do a little more research on this I feel like there should be a much easier way then searching through nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) helps, but you'll need to navigate manually through all the HTML which is quite a bit of a pain...

Here is for example something to print the games played with their scored in the first table:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JSoupTest {

    @Test
    public void testJSoup() throws IOException {
        String html = "http://beta.letsplaysoccer.com/facilities/26/teams/187822";

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();
        Elements tableElements = doc.select("table");

        Element firstTable = tableElements.get(0);

        List<Node> firstTableRows = firstTable.childNodes().get(1).childNodes();
        int numRows = firstTableRows.size();
        // skip first row as header
        for (int i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
            Node row = firstTableRows.get(i);
            if (row instanceof Element) {
                Node homeTeam = row.childNode(5).childNode(1).childNode(0);
                Node visitorTeam = row.childNode(7).childNode(1).childNode(0);
                // some are in bold
                if(visitorTeam.childNodeSize() > 0 ){
                    visitorTeam = visitorTeam.childNode(0);
                }
                Node score = row.childNode(9).childNode(0);
                System.out.println(homeTeam + " vs " + visitorTeam + ": " + score);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you maybe add a little more explanation in the code? What is "Node" used for and how does childNode(x) work?

Comment: I guess what I am wondering is how did you know the score is row.childNode(9).childNode(0)? How would I add the date or something?

Comment: Basically you have to navigate through an XML structure (which is tree shaped). Each node of the tree will have child (ie and XML element will have child XML elements). The problem here is that any text sequence including spaces will count as an element too, so it's a bit tricky. I found out the right numbers by basically stepping/debugging through the code. Add breakpoints in your IDE and look at the Node/Element you are interested in; it has a childNode list/array... find out the one you want.